# Is TkKinter widely used to build user interfaces?

Tags: python, tkinter

In which kind of application is Tkinter usually used?

I'm doing a project in Python in which I'm using it for the first time to build a simple user interface.

I was wondering if this is widely used for specific applications, or mobile applications.. etc

Comment: Tkinter is fine for building GUIs (although other, bigger GUI toolkits have advantages, and you propably want to use them for a big application) and also fine for learning to do so. Just go ahead and use it instead of worrying about this.

Comment: @delnan thanks, what about Qt wxWidgets ? I mean.. are these GUI toolkit for python widely used to build applications ? Which kind of applications? mobile ? desktop ?

Comment: "widely used"?  As in used in many different countries?  Or as in used throughout the history of Python?  What does "widely used" mean?

Comment: @S.Lott No I didn't mean in the history of programming, I meant across continents nowadays

Comment: Perhaps you could **update** your question to define what you mean by "widely used".

Comment: May be the question meant, is it popular enough to showcase a tkinter based project as sometime spent on worthwhile project, while the state of the art of more popular platforms say PyQt may be received as something new and contemporary. Is there a list of applications that use tkinter that is available and popular with users ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I have seen, Tkinter is great for simple applications, teaching, or for when you don't need the features of a more comprehensive package like Qt or wxWidgets. These libraries can run several megabytes, and you may not need that. It's part of the standard library, so it's suited for this purpose. However, if you need more features, then Tkinter may not be the best choice.

Tkinter also used to look really ugly because it drew its own widgets on each platform; however, I think the version included with Python 2.7 uses native widgets now.

I don't think there are any specific applications; it's a general purpose library.

Comment: thanks, what about Qt wxWidgets ? I mean.. are these GUI toolkit for python widely used to build applications ? Which kind of applications? mobile ? desktop ?

Comment: They are all general-purpose libraries and they don't really have any specific applications, except that they are desktop libraries. If you're going for mobile apps or web apps, you're looking for something else - possibly Appcelerator Titanium. If you choose Qt, it has built-in webkit support, if that's important.

Comment: @i33tnerd thanks.. so I know I'm going a bit out of question theme.. what are the most used GUI toolkit for Android and Iphone ?

Comment: Ehh...I have no idea at all. Maybe HTML/CSS? That would be a separate question...are you making a mobile app?

Comment: @i33tnerd I'm planning to start soon, I will do some research.. thanks

Answer (score 0):

PyQt is a python binding of the popular Qt GUI toolkit. its very comprehensive.Anyway tkinter is good to start with and later you can move to PyQt or wxWidgets

Comment: Is there a way to directly translate Tkinter to Qt and then improvise from there ?